# What characters are html encoded?

Tags: c#, soap

**TL;DR** D&#252;sseldor is encoded to D&amp;#252;sseldor, Düsseldorf isn't encoded (by the default MVC encoding) why?

I'm building an api with soap access. When I get a request I html encode all the data.
Just before I end the current request I copy the Response.Stream and save it for logging.

I noticed that Düsseldorf is encoded by my api to "D&#252;sseldorf". This is expected.
But in my logs it shows Düsseldorf encoded as "D&amp;#252;sseldorf" ( double encoded ) my logs saves after the MVC serializes writes to the response stream.

I think this is because soap encodes values before sending them over the wire.

So my next test was to turn off html encoding in my api.
So this time Düsseldorf was giving to the soap serializer.

But it was encoded as Düsseldorf?

EDIT: When I say I turn on / off the encoding what I mean is each field in the request I use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("some field"). And save that to the database. Then I return the data with an MVC view like so:

```
public ActionResult CreateAccessCode ( CreateAccessCodeRequest request )
{
    var response = new Response (request);
    return new ContentResult (response);
}
```

My question is when the ContentResult method runs, it seems to do some encoding of its own and I was wondering what that was?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. If you disabled html encoding, wouldn't that be the expected result? Also, what was in your logs when you turned off html encoding?

Answer (score 2):

SOAP uses XML - HTML and XML require slightly different encoding, but it may or may not be a problem in your case.

Much more likely your manual construction of XML is not correct. Please *do not* construct XML with string concatenation - XDocument/XmlDocument are much more suitable for that.

Comment: If i have a good memory, i remember using the class XmlDocument, and adding childrens/values, obtain the document with applied encoding.
Try using `System.Xml.XmlDocument`

Comment: I don't manually create the xml. I use the built in .net methods

Comment: @user1909158 your statement "I html encode all the data" does not sound right in light of  "I use the built in .net methods (working with XML)". You probably should update your question with sample text /code so it is clear what problem you have.